# Calculation of having at least 1 record in a given datetime and at least 1 record coming for each datetime in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

I have an aggregated table from this query:

```
select userid, count(1) as count, date, itemname
from clickitem
where itemname in ('Allowance', 'Records') and
      date >= date_sub(current_date,3) and
      date <= date_sub(current_date,1)
group by userid, itemname, date
order by count, date
```

Sample Result:

| userid | itemname | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06d50c86 | Allowance | 2021-08-14 | 4 |
| 06d50c86 | Records | 2021-08-14 | 1 |
| 06d50c86 | Records | 2021-08-13 | 3 |
| 06d50c86 | Allowance | 2021-08-13 | 2 |
| 06d50c86 | Records | 2021-08-12 | 1 |
| 06d50c86 | Allowance | 2021-08-12 | 1 |
| 11751723 | Records | 2021-08-13 | 2 |
| 13cc24cc | Allowance | 2021-08-14 | 3 |

The need is:

I need to seperate userids' in four conditions:

- Flag userid having count at least one per day in current date minus 3 days. (If today is 2021-08-15' then count>=1 for date ='2021-08-14', '2021-08-13' and '2021-08-12')
  for the itemname : Records
- Again, Flag userid having count at least one per day in current date minus 3 days but for the itemname : Allowance
- Flag userid having count at least one in current date minus 3 days. (Flag if there is at least one record in any of the last three days, count>=1 for '2021-08-12' is okay)
  for the itemname : Allowance
- Again, Flag userid having count at least one in current date minus 3 days but for the itemname : Records

The expected (aggregated from the source table) output should be like:

| userid | itemname | date | viewedEveryDay | viewedAtLeastOne |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06d50c86 | Allowance | 2021-08-14 | 1 | 1 |
| 06d50c86 | Records | 2021-08-14 | 1 | 1 |
| 06d50c86 | Allowance | 2021-08-13 | 1 | 1 |
| 06d50c86 | Records | 2021-08-12 | 1 | 1 |
| 06d50c86 | Allowance | 2021-08-12 | 1 | 1 |
| 11751723 | Records | 2021-08-13 | 0 | 1 |
| 13cc24cc | Allowance | 2021-08-14 | 0 | 1 |

*viewedEveryDay = 1 because user 06d50c86 visited the relevant itemname on all three days, If he didn't visit itemname = Records every day, he would have viewedEveryDay=0.
All flags should set 0 when a left outer join is done to the table in another query.*

We could have done the calculation by entering the dates one by one in where, but since the table structure is dynamic, it will take the last 3 days as the flow runs. How can I write this query under these conditions?

Comment: For the case of `viewedAtLeastOne = 0`, where do we find that `userid` and `itemname`?  Is there a `user` table?  Do you want to show all users in the result, even if 99% of them did not view items in the last 3 days?  Is there an `items` table to obtain that list of items, in case some items are not viewed at all in the past 3 days?

Comment: I used the query in the first step then create my source table, trying to produce the sample output (second table) according to that. userid and relevant itemname is already given. The all users will be shown because all of them had viewed at least one itemname, Allowance and/or Records.  The question I am trying to answer from the created table is: For each itemname, has the userid clicked on the itemname every day within a certain day range? or is there at least one click count for that itemname in a certain day range? @JonArmstrong

Comment: Sure.  But that wasn't really my question. So when you say "for each item", you really mean "for each item viewed at least once within the last 3 days", correct?  And when you ask for user detail, you're asking about only those users which have viewed at least one item within the last 3 days, correct?  The fact that you found all items and all users in this particular 3 days isn't really the point of my question.

Comment: We should consider separately the itemnames that the userid displays. For example, if a userid visits the Records page, and does this for every day in the time range given in the query, then viewedEveryDay = 1. Since he will have visited at least 1 time, viewedAtLeastOne = 1 will come. Just because he visits Records doesn't mean he visits Allowance every day, either. Allowance should be looked at separately. If the userid has no records of Allowance (12-13-14) for all dates given in the query, then viewedEveryDay = 0. We can think of the userid and the itemname displayed by the userid as a grp

Comment: I think I did it. select userid, dy, itemname, case when count(userid) over (partition by userid, itemname) >=1
    then 'Y' else 'N' end as viewedAtLeastOne, 
case when count(distinct dy) over (partition by userid, itemname) >=7 then 'Y' else 'N' end as viewedEveryDay
    from aggregatedtable @JonArmstrong